# Joining/Merge two keys to one key and removing duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql, toad

I want to merge two tables using SQL (Toad for Oracle) merging one key from one table to two keys of the main table while deleting the duplicated entries. I guess an illustration provides you better understanding of my problem:

Dataframe A:

```
    Key1 Key2 ColA 
    1     2    1993
    1     2    1992
    1     4    1991
    2     4    1990
    2     5    1989 
    2     5    1988
    3     5    1987
    3     6    1986
    3     6    1985
```

Dataframe B:

```
Key1&2  ColB
1       Adress1
1       Adress1
1       Adress1
2       Adress2
2       Adress2
3       Adress3
3       Adress3
3       Adress3
4       Adress4
4       Adress4
5       Adress5
6       Adress6
6       Adress6
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
Key1 Key2 ColA  ColB-1     ColB-2
1     2    1993 Adress1   Adress2
1     2    1992 Adress1   Adress2 
1     4    1991 Adress1   Adress4
2     4    1990 Adress2   Adress4
2     5    1989 Adress2   Adress5
2     5    1988 Adress2   Adress5
3     5    1987 Adress3   Adress5
3     6    1986 Adress3   Adress6
3     6    1985 Adress3   Adress6
```

I tried using following statement so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.key1=B.key1&2
LEFT JOIN B ON A.key2=B.key1&2
```

However, as I explained, because dataframe B has duplicated rows in its keys, duplicated rows in my output as well.
Hope its clear.

Thanks,

KS

Comment: You have no `'Adress6'` or `'Adress5'` in your data.  Where do these come from?

Comment: It comes from dataframe B. I edited my post.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT A.*, B1.ColB, B2.ColB
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT key1&2, ColB
      FROM B
     ) B1 ON A.key1 = B1.key1&2 LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT DISTINCT key1&2, ColB
      FROM B
     ) B2 ON A.key2 = B2.key1&2;
```

Comment: Where does B1 & B2 come from? There is only one dataset B.

Comment: What is "seems not to work as well" supposed to mean?  Do you get an error?  Or what?

Comment: 1. Where does the B1 & B2 come from? I only have one B data frame 2. The 2 subquerys after LEFT JOIN result in an error. I'm using Oracle DB, maybe its SQL-Language has another syntax?

Comment: @KostaS. . . . (1) `B1` and `B2` are table aliases and they are fine.  (2) The only obvious syntax issue is the name of the column `key1&2`, but that is how you express the columns and logic in your question.  The name should be escaped, but you don't do that in your question.